# How to mock a function from another file

Tags: go

I'm playing around with Golang and test cases in it, but it's almost completely different from other testing libraries in other languages (I'm with JS background)

In my file I have:

```
type MyHandler struct {
    myBool bool
    Person searchFile.Person
}
```

And lastly in my third file I have:

```
type Person interface {
    searchFor(name string) (string, error)
}
```

In my `main_test.go` I have the following line:

`h := &MyHandler{myBool: false}` <- how can I mock the `searchFor` function in Golang

Answer (score 0):

It's just an interface, so simply create a struct that implements the interface (and modify the interface so the method is exported, since it doesn't really make sense to have an unexported method in an interface):

```
type Person interface {
    SearchFor(name string) (string, error)
}

type MockSearcher struct{}

func (m MockSearcher) SearchFor(name string) (string, error) {
    return "mock name", nil
}

person := MockSearcher{}
h := &MyHandler{myBool: false, Person: person}
```

Comment: https://blog.chewxy.com/2018/03/18/golang-interfaces/#sealed-interfaces

Comment: @mh-cbon keep in mind that all one needs to do to "break the seal" is to embed `Fooer`.

Comment: will check for it, I stucked on `Only the package that defined Fooer can use and create any valid value of Fooer. `

Answer (score 0):

You can embed that interface !

```golang
package main

import (
    "play.ground/sealed"
)

type sealedStruct struct {
    sealed.Interface
}

func (s sealedStruct) sealed() {}

var j sealed.Interface = sealedStruct{}

func main() {
}

-- go.mod --
module play.ground

-- sealed/interface.go --
package sealed

type Interface interface {
    sealed()
}

-- sealed/interface_test.go --
package sealed_test

import "test/d/sealed"

type sealedStruct struct {
    sealed.Interface
}

func (s sealedStruct) sealed() {}

var j sealed.Interface = sealedStruct{}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ic_TnrLlF_u